# Group Items together that share the same ID Code, then indicate that the item is part of a group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, syntax, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have items in a table that resemble the following:

| Item | FamilyCode |
| --- | --- |
| ABR123 | ABR |
| ABR456 | ABR |
| BCL369 | BCL |
| BCL987 | BCL |
| AEL877 | AEL |

I would like to notate whether an item is part of a family based on the whether there are other items that exist with this same family code.  I would like to add an output column such as  "Is Part of a Family", Yes/No.

The output would be as follows:

| Item | FamilyCode | Is Part of a Family? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABR123 | ABR | Yes |
| ABR456 | ABR | Yes |
| BCL369 | BCL | Yes |
| BCL987 | BCL | Yes |
| AEL877 | AEL | No |

Comment: Use a windowed `COUNT` with a `CASE` (or `IIF`) and if the value is `1` then return `'No'` otherwise `'Yes'`?

Comment: Though, thinking about it now, I don't think `IIF` existed in SQL Server 2008 (R2), I think it was added in SQL Server 2012. Really, however, you should be finalising and implementing your upgrade path; SQL Server 2008 (R2) ran *completely* out of support well over 3 years ago.

Comment: @Larnu, I completely agree.  However, I am not in charge of those decisions.  Needs to be done though!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished by counting the number of rows with the same FamilyCode and, if it's greater than 1, mark it as part of a family. Something like this:

```sql
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        ('ABR123', 'ABR'),
        ('ABR456', 'ABR'),
        ('BCL369', 'BCL'),
        ('BCL987', 'BCL'),
        ('AEL877', 'AEL')
    ) as x([Item], [FamilyCode])
)
select *,
    [IsPartOfFamily] =
        case when count(*) over (partition by [FamilyCode]) > 1 
        then 1
        else 0 end
from cte;
```